# How to get the contents of a any source file

Tags: php, parsing, curl

Example: When the url is http://www.google.com

I know, how to get the contents and how to parse it by `file_get_contents` or `curl` method.

So, My question is: **How to get the contents and to parse the source file of that webpage.**

For Example: view-source: http://www.google.com

When I am trying to parse the above source file, I found that the file contents are not getting loaded initially for parsing.

So I need a help regarding,

How to load the contents of `view-source:http://www.google.com` page.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php or http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Sorry, wut? You already know how to get the contents using curl... what other source are you looking for? What specific problem do you have loading it?

Comment: the content IS the source. 'view-source:' ist just the browser telling you that it is showing you the source instead of rendering it.

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents` and `view-source` in the chrome browser should return the same thing - the **HTML** code of the page. If you're trying to get the code behind that HTML (PHP, .net, etc...) - you can't.

`view-source` is showing you the **exact same thing** as the code, returned by `cUrl` or `file_get_contents`, and it's a feature in the Chrome browser only - it's not a valid URL address scheme.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:
"For Example: view-source: http://www.google.com

When I am trying to parse the above source file, I found that the file contents are not getting loaded"

And here is the problem: `view-source:` is a feature of chrome -- not a valid url. That's why the contents don't get loaded. The php functions need a valid url: http://www.google.com from which it can load the source.

Answer (score 2):

You get web page content by file_get_contents("http://www.google.com"); not file_get_contents("view-source: http://www.google.com");

Then you parse it with:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

If php DOM API can't do the parsing, you can try PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/